# extract value from both array and object for a field

Tags: json, if-statement, jq

In the below json, the .Principal.AWS contains value in one and array of values in another. If its an array I am using join to combine the values and then  for object i am getting error

jq: error (at stackflow.json:46): Cannot iterate over string ("arn:aws:ia...)

I tried jq even by using if type = "array" but getting error .

```
E:\python_test>jq-win32.exe -r ".RoleName + \"  \" + (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[] | select (.Principal.AWS? != "null") | (.Principal.AWS |join (\"###\")) ) "  stackflow.json

allow-test-account-to-hostedzones  arn:aws:iam::426544XX7585196:root###arn:aws:iam::640XXX556689289:root
jq: error (at stackflow.json:46): Cannot iterate over string ("arn:aws:ia...)
```

```
{
    "RoleName": "AccessKeyRotation-LambdaRole",
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "RoleName": "allow-test-account-to-hostedzones",
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::426544XX7585196:root",
                        "arn:aws:iam::640XXX556689289:root"
                    ]
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "RoleName": "allow-test-env-access-to-route53",
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::445666XX779289:root"
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The expected result is

```
allow-test-account-to-hostedzones arn:aws:iam::426544XX7585196:root###arn:aws:iam::640XXX556689289:root
allow-test-env-access-to-route53 arn:aws:iam::445666XX779289:root
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that you wrote `"null"` instead of `null`.

The following jq filter produces the desired result:

```
.RoleName + " " +
  (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[]
   | select( .Principal.AWS? != null )
   | .Principal.AWS
   | if type == "array" then join("###") else tostring end )
```

To avoid problems with presenting this filter to a Windows interpreter, I'd suggest putting the program in a file, which is probably a good idea anyway.